# how to get the "old" row in mysql trigger on updating a data?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

How can I get the old row(the row has been replaced by the newly update row) in mysql trigger? For example, if I want to get the newly update row, I can just use NEW, but when it comes to the old row, I thought it was OLD, but it didn't work. so what's the answer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to fix code, please provide example DB structure and SQL statements of what you want to achieve, or what you have tried so far.

Comment: See [14.1.20 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).